# Is database operation atomic

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

If multi thread concurrently query the following SQL to a database(postgresql):

```
UPDATE mytable SET n=n+1 WHERE n=0;
```

Whether or not 'n' will finally greater than 1

Comment: Assuming you're using transactions, then [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/about/) *is fully ACID compliant* where **ACID** is *Atomic*, *Consistent*, *Isolated* and *Durable*.

Comment: If not use transaction, does this operation atomic?

Comment: There are many operations here. It's not atomic in the sense that the read and write are different steps. In this case it's *safe* because the update takes a lock on the row and holds it until it writes the new version and exits.

Comment: Result may depend on the transaction isolation level. I don't know what is the default level in Postgres and how it is implemented. Different levels provide different guarantees, so you'd better read the docs on this subject. Keep in mind, that even if you don't wrap this statement in a transaction explicitly, most likely there still would be an implicit transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Update will take write lock, so no concurrent operation will actually happen on the table.

```
n will not be greater than 1.
```

Comment: Doesn't Postgres use row versioning without any locks? I may be wrong, I'm just curious.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Now with *lock capable* [mvcc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html).

Answer (score 0):

> `update mytable set n=n+1 where n=0;`
>
> Whether or not 'n' will finally greater than 1

No it will not be "*greater than 1*" because adding `1` to `0` yields `1`.

So `n` will be **equal** to `1`, not "*greater than 1*".

And yes, it is *guaranteed* that all values that were previously 0 (zero) are 1 (one) after the update has finished without an error.

Comment: The tricky part here is "previously". What if a row with `n=0` is inserted while this update is running? What if another concurrent update sets n to 0 where n=1? I think it is important to know the transaction isolation level. Most likely, n will not be greater than 1, but it could well end up with some rows that still have n=0.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: a (DML) statement sees a consistent state of the database while the statement runs - the state the database was in at the moment when the statement started.